# ¿Cómo quitar los días cuando hago un TimeSpan.FromMinutes en Informe c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, rdlc

tengo un informe en c# de totales en donde sumo los minutos que un trabajador que ha trabajado una serie de horas, pero sin embargo en la expresión si el trabajador se ha pasado más de 24 horas trabajando me añade los días. No quiero que se muestren los días sino el total de horas. Aquí les dejo el código de la Expresión y la imagen para corroborar que me salen los días.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el código de la expresión. Gracias por su atención.

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Sum(CInt(Fields!suma_minutos.Value)))
```

Según lo que me digeron me aparece de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Falta código: ¿Qué hay a la izquierda del igual `=`? ¿A qué tipo de datos pertenece `suma_minutos`? ¿Qué es `Fields`?

Comment: suma_minutos es de tipo entero, fields!suma_minutos es un campo del conjunto de datos que tenemos

Comment: no esta muy claro..o sea, si por ejemplo ha trabajado 2 dias, quieres que en los minutos aparezca 48:xx:xx?

Comment: Por ejemplo, en la imagen que está arriba aparece en el total 1(dia).00(horas):10(minutos):00(segundos), pues yo quiero que aparezca 24(horas):10(minutos):00 (segundos)

Comment: No es muy complicado hacerlo en código, pero no se si en el rdlc podrás hacerlo ya que está un poco limitado. Voy a añadir una respuesta ya que es un poco extenso para un comentario.

Comment: @SergioDavidPerezAcosta falta código, añádelo, no lo comentes.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster creo que no falta código. En un informe RDLC, los valores de las celdas de un grid pueden llevar una expresión de su valor, que se define como `=expresión` (similar al excel). Creo que es lo que usa el op y por eso no había nada a la izquierda del `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que el rdlc es un poco limitado, yo te recomendaría añadir un nuevo campo, por ejemplo `suma_minutos_str`, e inicializarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var tmsp = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(suma_minutos); //aqui en suma_minutos el valor que has calculado
var suma_minutos_str= $"{tmsp.Days*24+tmsp.Hours}:{tmsp.Minutes.ToString("00")}:{tmsp.Seconds.ToString("00")}";
```

De esta manera en `suma_minutos_str` tienes un string en el que se suman los dias multiplicados por 24 a las horas "sueltas", y se le añaden los minutos y los segundos. Luego, es esa variable la que debes usar en el RDLC.

Comment: Voy a probarlo a ver si me funciona

Comment: Oye ya puse tu código en el mío y me muestra el informe bien con horas y minutos, pero lo que me falta ahora es sumar tanto las horas como los minutos. Como puedo hacerlo?